# RubyTest Sublime Text 2 not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sublimetext2, ruby-test

I've been messing around with this for well over an hour and still can't get RubyTest working within Sublime Text 2. Each time that I attempt to run a test I get a simple message that " 'rspec' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I tried both the clone from github method of installing RubyTest, as well as via Package Installer with the same results. I'm launching Sublime Text 2 via "subl ." from my application's directory.

I know I'm just missing something simple, but all of the fixes I've found on the web are specific to non-Windows environments and I haven't been able to adapt the answers to my circumstances.

I am NOT using pik or any other Ruby version manager.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Figured it out, needed to prefix "bundle exec" to the "rspec" command in my User - RubyTest.sublime-settings file to get it to work.

Comment: I think there is an option to add answer to your question, can you please do it instead of having the solution as the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, needed to prefix "bundle exec" to the "rspec" command in my User - RubyTest.sublime-settings file to get it to work. –  Rob Jan 29 '13 at 20:26